# Azure DevOps. Generate Unique Variable

Tags: azure-devops

We are in need of generating unique names for some of our resources via YAML Pipelines. What syntax can we use to do that?

Comment: It will be better if you could describe your issue with detailed information such as examples and screenshots, you could refer to other answered posts. BTW, you could try to use [predefined variables like run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) as the resources name.

Comment: Well the issues is simple: if we don't provide unique names for some of our scripts they fail. `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)` would do the trick, but it simply doesn't work `echo $(Date:yyyyMMdd)` outputs `/home/vsts/work/_temp/3f7ad7f3-6c65-4333-9a67-2a26184de491.sh: line 2: Date:yyyyMMdd: command not found`.

Comment: Have a look at the [counter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions#counter) in pipeline expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(Date:yyyyMMdd)` is format instead of variable, you get the error: `line 2: Date:yyyyMMdd: command not found`

> Well the issues is simple: if we don't provide unique names for some of our scripts they fail.

You could [define variable via command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) and then use it in the scrips, or use [predefined build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services), such as `Build.BuildId`. Then we could provide unique names for the script.